# Google Sheets slow - 1. mobile? 2. why? 3. importrange

Tags: google-sheets, import, mobile

Update: Google Sheets is much faster when using Incognito

1. Google Sheets is so slow on desktop but really fast on mobile. Is it supposed to be like that? If so, why? If not, what are some factors that might lead to this? Usually the google sheets I open have a lot of filter functions in the opening tab. Might that cause slowing down?
2. In general, does having a lot of formulas, ***in particular filter or query***, mean a lot of loading? In this case I was thinking to just copy then paste as values.
3. If sheet X importranges from sheets A,B and C, then would, for example, A slow down because X importranges from it? I get X would slow down since opening it would be running the importranges but what about A?

Comment: This looks like a to be a too broad question.

Comment: @pnuts wish I could delete. Man incognito is great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. On the desktop it's running as JavaScript code inside a browser. On the mobile it's a native app, and also has more limited functionality. That can explain the difference. I'm not sure but it's also possible that it offloads some processing to server side.
2. In general, hard to say, but rather not -- the last calculated values are stored and loaded with the sheet. Depending on what the formulas do, if each formula processes lots of data (SUMPRODUCT or MMULT come to mind here), this could certainly slow down recalculation, but not loading.
3. No. For the above mentioned reason - last calculated values are stored until there is a reason to recalculate them.

Comment: Thanks ttarchala! Follow up for #1: how might I limit functionality in web app? I don't have any add ons I believe. Edited for #2: same answer for filter? query?

Comment: @BCLC: "Follow up questions" should be posted as questions (see [ask])

Comment: Never mind. I found out that incognito helps so much. Thanks anyway! ^-^